# Configuring admin APIs in client project

Tags: java, spring

I need to use admin API in my client project. How do I create/inject the adminAPI bean into the client project.

Here is the Admin API:

```
@Configuration
public class QOCAdminConfig
{
 
    @Bean
    public QOCAdminSettings qocAdminSettings()
    {
        return new QOCAdminSettings();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public QOCAdminEndpoint qocAdminEndpoint()
    {
        QOCAdminSettings settings = qocAdminSettings();
        AccessTokenSource serviceAuth = new ServiceAuth(settings.authUrl, settings.authUser, settings.authSecret);
        EndpointConfig config = EndpointConfig.builder()
                .withBaseUrl(settings.partnerAdminUrl)
                .withServiceAuth(serviceAuth)
                .withFailureHandler(new PartnerAdminFailureHandler())
                .build();
        return new QOCAdminEndpoint(config);
    }
   
    public static class QOCAdminSettings
    {
        @Value("${qoc.gatewayService.auth.user}")
        private String authUser;
        
        @Value("${qoc.gatewayService.auth.secret}")
        private String authSecret;
        
        @Value("${qoc.gatewayService.auth.url}")
        private String authUrl;
        
        @Value("${qoc.partnerAdmin.url}")
        private String partnerAdminUrl;

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "QOCAdminSettings [authUser=" + authUser + ", authSecret=" + authSecret + ", authUrl="
                    + authUrl + ", partnerAdminUrl=" + partnerAdminUrl + "]";
        }
       
        
    }
}
```

In my client code I need to use the endpoint methods like,the client project is using old spring version4.1.5.RELEASE

```
@Autowired
 QOCAdminEndpoint endpoint;

endpoint.getSelectedEndpoint();
```

How to define these configs in my client code.

Comment: Hey @madhu, the configuration class is located on a different project? Are you importing it as a maven dependency?

Comment: yes the configuration is in different project and importing as maven dependency

Answer (score 0):

To include the admin API in your project, all you need to do is to make sure the components of the lib are being included inside Spring's application context.

To do so, you have a couple of alternatives. I'm assuming your client project has a Configuration class of its own.

**@ComponentScan**

Using [@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html), you may scan the root package of the AdminAPI lib. It will scan for the components inside the lib and make them available on Spring Context

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.admin.project") //replace with dependency's base package
public class ClientProjectConfig {
    
    @Bean
    pulblic SomeBean someLocalBean() {
        .....
    }
}
```

**@Import**

You can also use [@Import](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) to specify the lib's Configuration class. It will give you a bit more control over what Beans you are including in your context since it will not scan the entire package.

```
@Configuration
@Import(QOCAdminConfig.class)
public class ClientProjectConfig {

    @Bean
    pulblic SomeBean someLocalBean() {
        .....
    }
}
```

Here is a useful link also: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-import-annotation

Comment: Thank you so much. once I use @Imort, how do I pass "qoc.gatewayService.auth.user" properties into the bean? shall I pass those values using xml config?

Comment: Hey @madhu , you can use Autowired QOCAdminSettings to inject the settins in any class you'd like. Then you can just qocAdminSettings.getAuthUser(). Im guessing those fields have a Getter declared. If not, you cannot access them since they are private.

Please dont forget to vote and mark the answer if it was useful for you. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Diego, can you show me how do I call qocAdminEndpoint() bean in my client class (ClientProjectConfig) which should initialize qocAdminSettings() with the values I added in property file in  my client project.

Comment: Sorry @madhu, I don't understand the question. I advise you to post a different question and search a bit about how DI works.